# How can I make the camera to rotate from side side but in static movement range?

Tags: unity, c#

I mean for some reason now the camera is rotating to the left and to the right but sometimes it's rotating to one of the sides a lot I mean a very sharp angle and sometimes less rotation.

How can I control how much rotation will be from side to side by degrees ?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class scr_camera : MonoBehaviour {

    public float rotate_amount;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles.x, (Mathf.Sin(Time.realtimeSinceStartup) * rotate_amount) + transform.eulerAngles.y, transform.eulerAngles.z);
    }
}
```

[image: Camera]

Sometimes cam14 make almost 240 even close to 300 degrees rotation to one of the sides sometimes less. The rotation is not equal to both sides. I want simple rotation to both side just to see the room and not the walls behind the camera.

In this case I set the rotate_amount to 7 so it will rotate faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class scr_camera: MonoBehaviour {

    public float rotate_amount;
    float initialAngle;

    void Start() {
        initialAngle = transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
    }

    void Update() {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles.x, (Mathf.Sin(Time.realtimeSinceStartup)/2 * rotate_amount) + initialAngle, transform.eulerAngles.z);
    }
}
```

Notice that first we need to store the initial rotation, in order to add the offset we calculate.

If you simply add the offset to the current rotation like this:

```
(Mathf.Sin(Time.realtimeSinceStartup) * rotate_amount) + transform.eulerAngles.y
```

`rotate_amount` will be not setting the maximun rotation, but the maximun rotation speed.